# How can we save xquery output data on shared location of another system that not have Marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

We need to save fetched data on another system shared location. And, the shared location system does not have Marklogic.

How to do this in Marklogic?

We are using version 8 of the MarkLogic server.

Answer (score 1):

The MarkLogic servers don't need direct access to where the data is stored. Rather than having the MarkLogic server *pull* the data in, you can use a client to *push* the data to MarkLogic and insert. You just need a client that can access the data on that shared mount AND that can communicate with MarkLogic to send the data in.

There are a variety of tools and APIs available that can load data into MarkLogic, depending upon what sort of shared location you are referring to (Unix mount, Windows shared drive, S3, etc.) and whether talking to MarkLogic via HTTP using the out of the box REST APIs [PUT /v1/documents](https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/REST/PUT/v1/documents), [POST /v1/eval](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/eval), a custom endpoint executing your own module, or using the [XCC](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xcc/intro) protocol.

For [tools and connectors](https://www.marklogic.com/product/getting-started/#Tools) to load data, there is MarkLogic's [MLCP](https://developer.marklogic.com/products/mlcp-2/) and [CoRB](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/) as well as the [Java](https://developer.marklogic.com/products/java/) and [Node.js](https://developer.marklogic.com/products/node/) API and a number connectors for [MuleSoft](https://developer.marklogic.com/products/mulesoft/), [NiFi](https://developer.marklogic.com/products/nifi/), [Spark](https://developer.marklogic.com/products/spark/), and [Glue](https://developer.marklogic.com/products/awsglue/).

Comment: We are getting Marklogic GET REST API requests with two-parameter,
1. Eligibility query, we need to fetch data from the MarkLogic based on this query.
2. Shared path location [Windows shared drive, i.e. //{IP address}/{shared_folder}], there we need to save this fetched data.

We are stuck on point 2, how can we access the shared location path in MarkLogic?

Comment: If the MarkLogic servers cannot access the shared drive, maybe have something running on a client that *can* access it, and expose an HTTP endpoint that MarkLogic can POST the data to, which would then save to that drive? https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:http-post